# Fixing K nearest neighbor algorithm function in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, nearest-neighbor

I modified a function based on a nearest neighbor algorithm that takes the parameters x and y from a list of randomly generated values to plot points on a graph based, but the edges are being plotted out wrong and I can't figure out why.

Here is the original algorithm I based my code on

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

xy = np.random.rand(40, 2)

plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
dist_sq = np.sum((xy[:,np.newaxis,:] - xy[np.newaxis,:,:]) ** 2, axis=-1)
#nearest = np.argsort(dist_sq, axis=1)
K = 1
nearest_partition = np.argpartition(dist_sq, K+1, axis=1)
plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
#plt.scatter(xy[:,0], xy[:,1], s=40)

for i in range(xy.shape[0]):
    for j in nearest_partition[i, :K+1]:
        plt.plot(*zip(xy[j], xy[i]), color='black')
```

and here is my function

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def nearest_neighbor_graph(x, y, k, pcolor='blue', psize=20, ecolor='black', figsize=(6,6)):
  plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))
  plt.scatter(x, y, psize, color = pcolor)
  dist_sq = np.sum((xy[:,np.newaxis,:] - xy[np.newaxis,:,:]) ** 2, axis=-1)
  nearest = np.argsort(dist_sq, axis=1)
  #nearest_partition = np.argpartition(dist_sq, k + 1, axis=1)
  for i in range(xy.shape[0]):
    for j in nearest[i, :k + 1]:
        plt.plot(*zip(xy[i], xy[j]), color= ecolor)
  

np.random.seed(10)
xy = np.random.rand(2, 40)
nearest_neighbor_graph(xy[0], xy[1], 1, ecolor='red', psize=50)
nearest_neighbor_graph(xy[0], xy[1], 2, pcolor='green', psize=100, ecolor='black')
```

In my function, when I get to the `nearest_partition` line I get an error so I use `nearest` instead in its place in the bottom loop

```
for i in range(xy.shape[0]):
    for j in nearest[i, :k + 1]:
        plt.plot(*zip(xy[i], xy[j]), color= ecolor)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Comment: are we looking at the original code or the function ?   please clarify with a minimal example:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: The original code at the top is the working part, and the function at the bottom is the part that isn't working. The original code produces a scatter plot graph with a random number of marks with `xy = np.random.rand(40, 2)` and the graph is plotted at 'plt.scatter(xy[:,0], xy[:,1], s=40)'. Up to there, the bottom function works fine, with plotting the points, my problem is that the edges that are graphed are not plotting correctly like they do in the code above.

Comment: i will just point out that you have used 2 space indents (pep=4)... i have solved it, you were close.

Answer (score 0):

You were really close.  The error message was the clue:

```
ValueError: kth(=2) out of bounds (2)
```

checked the array size with `np.shape()` and it was 40x40, so then checked the syntax which was incorrect. You can see the corrected line.

so this works:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def nearest_neighbor_graph(x, y, k, pcolor='blue', psize=20, ecolor='black', figsize=(6,6)):
  plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))
  plt.scatter(x, y, psize, color = pcolor)
  dist_sq = np.sum((xy[:,np.newaxis,:] - xy[np.newaxis,:,:]) ** 2, axis=-1)
  # nearest = np.argsort(dist_sq, axis=1) 
  nearest_partition = np.argpartition(dist_sq, kth= 1, axis=1)
  for i in range(xy.shape[0]):
    for j in nearest_partition[i, :k + 1]:
        plt.plot(*zip(xy[i], xy[j]), color= ecolor)
  

np.random.seed(10)
xy = np.random.rand(2, 40)
nearest_neighbor_graph(xy[0], xy[1], 1, ecolor='red', psize=50)
nearest_neighbor_graph(xy[0], xy[1], 2, pcolor='green', psize=100, ecolor='black')
```

Here are the resulting graphs:

[image]

[image]